# Is there a way to do this "splitscreen" partially-rendered effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: splitscreen]

In this example (not my animation), the right half is rendered, while the left half is unrendered (like what you would see in the Viewport when set to Solid mode). As objects cross the center of the screen, they become rendered/unrendered.

This is done to show viewers what's going on behind the scenes, so they can see how the shot was constructed.

How could such an effect be created in Blender? I am particularly interested in doing the left half (the unrendered bit).

Comment: I'd use a render border to render only one half of the shot, then overlay that onto an OpenGL render.

Comment: If using nodes isn't needed (they won't be taken into account while in viewport) you can define a [render border](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/camera/introduction.html?highlight=render%20border#render-border); then while in camera view `Shift`+`Z` toggle will make render just like on refernce image.

Comment: How's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1jA.png) look?  (That's a frame from an animation which is too big to upload and I'm having trouble compressing it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may easily achieve this effect using ***Compositing Nodes***. I'll show you how to do it both for a *still image* and *animation*.

- ## ***STILL IMAGE***

[image]

First select the *Slot 1* in the *UV Editor* window and render your scene using a ***Full render*** (<kbd>F12</kbd>).
[image]
[image]

Then change the slot to *Slot 2*, but this time render the active viewport using the ***Open GL render***. Remove all the materials from your model. Check the ***Only Render*** checkbox, located in a *Display* panel of the *Properties Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>) and click the *camera icon* located at the bottom bar of the *3D window*.
[image]
[image]

Save both images to your computer.
[image]

Now go to the ***Node Editor***, press the ***Compositing nodes*** button and check the ***Use Nodes*** and ***Backdrop*** checkboxes. Then set up the nodes as pictured below. First add two ***Image*** nodes (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Input*-->*Image*) and open both images you've rendered. Next create a simple b&w texture in gimp (with the same resolution as rendered images).

[image]

Use it as a *Factor* for mixing two renders (add a ***Color*** node [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Color*-->*Mix*] and plug the image to its *Fac* socket. Add a ***Viewer*** node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Output*-->*Viewer*) to see the compositing result.
[image]

---

- ## ***ANIMATION***

  [image]

You may do it in similar way. Go to ***Render*** header and set up things as you like in *Dimensions* panel. In the *Output* panel choose the path to the folder you want your rendered frames to be saved (in my case I created a new folder and named it *'full render'*). Change the *file format* to ***JPEG***.
[image]

Now choose the ***Render Animation*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>).
[image]

When finished with rendering, change the path to another folder (I created a second one and called it 'openGL').
[image]

Press the ***OpenGL render animation*** button (the one next to *OpenGL render* button).
[image]

You have now two rendered image sequences in two folders. Set up the nodes as pictured below. Instead of adding *Image* nodes, add two ***Image Sequence*** ones (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Input*-->*Image Sequence*). Load the rendered pictures for each of them.
[image]

With setup like this go once again to the *Output* panel, click on the file directory browser and create a new folder for the final animation. Change the file format to for example ***AVI Raw***. Render your scene once again using <kbd>F12</kbd> button.
[image]

Comment: This has the disadvantage that you must render the entire image, only to crop off half of it, thus doubling rendertimes.

Comment: I would not say it's doubling the rendertimes, since OpenGL rendering is super fast (especially for scenes with no materials/textures). However you're right- that isn't a perfect method. I'm still thinking about doing it in a better/faster way. Maybe'll post another answer soon :).

Comment: You're right, it won't double the OpenGL rendertime, but it will for the normal render (almost).  I'm working on a way to do it with render borders, should be done in a few minutes.

Comment: Good point. A trick with overlaying half of the full render over the OpenGL one (as you said in your comment) will surely reduce the rendertime. Waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this by using a render border to render only half the image, then overlaying it onto an OpenGL render.

[[image]

First [set the render border](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44567/5705) to render only one half of the camera under *Outliner* (set to *Datablocks*) > *Scenes* > *[Scene Name]* > *Render Data*.  To render just the right half I set the *Border Minimum X* to `0.5`.

[image]

Then name your output file to something like `..._render_` and render out the image sequence as .PNGs.

Next rename your output file to something like `..._OpenGL_`.  Then (making sure you are in the camera view with <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>) render as an OpenGL animation from the 3D view footer or *Info* Header > *Render* > *OpenGL Render Animation*.

[image]

Now go the the *Video Sequence Editor* (VSE) and use *Add* > *Image* to import the two image sequences (one sequence at a time).  Place the `..._render_...` one above the `..._OpenGL_...` one.

[image]

Lastly, set the *Blend* on the top strip to *Alpha Over* under <kbd>N</kbd> toolbar > *Edit Strip*.

[image]

Now you're ready to change the output filename to something like `..._split_` and render normally with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Working on compressing the final render gif...