# Possible to set render border exactly

Tags: rendering, render-border

I know I can set the render border with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and dragging a box.  But is there  a way I can exactly specify the border dimensions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can access the render border values via the outliner if you change its display mode to 'Datablocks':

[image]

You can then navigate through the tree structure of the outliner to the border values via *Scenes> Scene* (may be different depending on the name of your actual scene)*> Render Data*:

[image]

The border values can be set from 0-1, so unfortunately you can't set exact pixel coordinates without some maths. 0 is the left side of the camera and 1 is the right side of the camera for the 'x' values (or the bottom and top sides of the camera for the 'y' values).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I actually prefer this way as opposed to pixel coords.

Comment: exactly what I needed in 2022. Same location, but now the Outliner is called Collections.
Collections Panel > Scenes > Scene > Render Data > Render Data > Render Region.

Comment: @hatinacat2000 I'm glad it still helps, but the Outliner has not been renamed.

Answer (score 18):

For more control I've written an Add-on which allows to set the *Render Border* in *Camera View*:

[image]

Install the [Add-on](https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder/releases) via *File > User Preferences > Add-ons*. Once it's enabled, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in the *Camera View* (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>), *select the Camera* and go to *Properties > Data > Render Border*.

**Half size**

[image]

**Shifting the box**

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder

Comment: Helpful addon! It's still a bit clunky to set it up to render out a section of an image at a fixed size, but infinitely easier than doing it without the addon.

Comment: This looks great!
Before I start digging deep in the code: would it theoretically be possible to write an addon which lets you draw a custom shape for the render border?
My use case is as follows: I have a nice shot but it contains also a great part of a white wall. So I'd like to set an L-shaped render border which leaves out the wall.