# Ways to speed up render of same scene multiple time with different textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I've recently come back to Blender after not using it for a while and I'm trying to reacquaint myself with everything.

I've been working on a model of a product to be used on a company's website. It's fairly simple, they supply boxes of different drinks to bars, restaurants etc. So the model is just a box which will have different labels on for each flavour.

There are around 50 variations and the render time takes around 25 - 30 minutes each.

Because the only thing that is changing is the textures for the labels I was wondering if there is anyway to either keep the parts of the scene that don't change pre-rendered, or to only render the areas around the labels and then layer those on top of a blank render of the box (in Blender itself or with Photoshop)?

I'm using Cycles if that makes a difference.

Comment: For the labels I'd suggest use the *render border*: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly

Comment: That looks like it could work well. But what size would the result be? If the whole image is 1000 x 1000 and I selected a 100 x 100 area. Would it give me a 100 x 100 image or 1000 x 1000 with blank space? If that makes sense

Comment: You can have both. If  *crop* is enabled *(Properties > Render > Dimensions)* then you'll get 100x100 otherwise you'll get the 1000x1000 with blank space.

Comment: That sounds perfect then, I was thinking for layering in Photoshop it would be a lot easier if it was the full size, as the area would be in the right position.

Comment: Further reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work

Comment: @poor  I would argue that that isn't a duplicate.  That question's answer may solve this problem, but they're certainly not *asking* the same thing at all.  There may even be other answers to this question which definitely don't belong with that question (like rendering out a texture coords pass and using a map UV node in the compositor).  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question).  Remember this question isn't just here for the OP, it's for anyone else who happens by here too.

Comment: @PGmath You are right. Voted for reopening too.