# How to render only a section of the screen?

Tags: rendering

I am rendering a small animation with Alpha that will be incorporated into a video. This animation will only occupy an area of 550 px wide by 650 px tall.
I know changing the Resolution in the Rendering tab is not the right way (as it keeps the same dimensions but with less resolution/pixels).
Maybe there’s a way to crop it? (just thinking out loud)

[image]

Comment: In addition to the current answer, I can recommend the **Animated Render Border** addon available on Blender Market, demonstrated [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61426/30849).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- The VSE Video Sequence Editor and Compositor can offset and clip images already created. These techniques can be animated.
- They can clip one image sequence and write those out to another set of files, another image sequence .
- Of course you can change the camera location to create a whole new set of images.

---

In case you want to see part of a render without changing the camera the User can use this technique. This seems likely for testing purposes only, yet that is your choice.  This technique saves time because part of the image will be solid or transparent and no further calculation. Above has mentioned that image sequences can be offset and clipped.

The image resolution is << not changed >>.

[image]
View Menu

Render Border

<kbd>Control-B</kbd>

Choose the Camera View first. Then keystroke and draw rectangle like box select. Test Render.

I will leave you to explore and search more.
You may be able to do that faster than my time allows me to write a lot of words