# How to change the resolution on a X or Y axis witouth having a scaling issue?

Tags: camera, resolution

How to change the resolution on a X or Y axis witouth having this weird scaling issue ?

for example, when searching a good ratio for a shot, you want to play and start changing the ratio of the rectangle of the shot as you wish , but blender after a certain point, (after hitting a 1:1 ratio ?), completely change the XY relations, i really dont understadn why, he start cropping the image on the other axis for some reasons... is this a bug ? i find this really annoying ... if anyone know a way to stop this behavior, either by tweaking a setting that i dont know (i tried tweaking aspect XY but same problem)with a add on, or a custom script somewhere ? please tell me

[image]
in this gif i only tweak the x resolution but somehow, blender re-crop on the Y axis

thanks

Comment: I think it also adapts to preserve the focal length.

Comment: If you want to render a region, you could try using Render Border (Ctrl B) instead.

Comment: i know but isnt the render border only used for testing ? in final you will need to recrop the image in another software anyway because when exporting the image blender will still export those non rendered pixels...

Comment: I don't use it but there is a Crop checkbox in the Render tab, so the output should be already cropped...?

Comment: You can also use Render Border addon that allows you to set it precisely: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly/45837#45837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apparent inconsistency is due to the camera Sensor Size being set to 'Auto'.

When set as 'Auto', Blender will use the specified sensor Size as the size of the longest edge of the sensor - and in your example this will correspond to the largest of the X and Y resolution. This means that whichever dimension is the largest will dictate the effective size of the sensor and this (in conjunction with the Focal Length) determines the view from the camera - hence the change in behaviour when the X dimension crosses the threshold of the Y dimension in your example.

The solution is to change the Sensor settings to Horizontal or Vertical. This locks the 'Size' to correspond to that specific axis.

[image: camera sensor size]

Comment: Oops.. I missed the point entirely... deleted.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, so blender dont offer more flexibility ? we are stuck choosing one or another? because the problem is still here, you are not really free to recrop the view as you want, like cropping in photoshop for examples, witouth the need to move your camera ?

Comment: okay so i just realised that this principle of cropping freely like photoshop will enter in conflict with having a more dense resolution... so my "free cropping" dream can't be done by tweaking the resolution. i want to do something similar as a border render, but with having the possibility to go ou of the shot ... i think the best way for me to do that is to shift the camera, and work my way with a bordered render with blank pixels deleted in photoshop.. but we need a more flexible croping solution in blender

Comment: @DorianBorremans The Camera Lens 'Shift' settings might help with you lining up the shot outside the normal frame - this allows you to shift the centre of the lens without moving the camera.