# Blender trim the rendered image to only visible objects

Tags: rendering, image

I am wondering if there is a way to trim the size of the rendered image to the edge of visible pixels for transparent PNGs. In Photoshop, I would go to Image -> Trim. I often render objects with transparent backgrounds that then need to be trimmed to the objects visible edge.

It would save a lot of time if I could skip editing the image in Photoshop.

Comment: To basically only render a certain area of the image right? Try whether the *render region* tool helps: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html?highlight=render%20region#render-region

Comment: @brockmann This looks like what I am trying to do. Can you create an answer for me? I would hope for something that would automatically detect the edge but I think this works.

Comment: Cool, all here already: [Possible to set render border exactly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly)