# Move Render Region With Animation

Tags: rendering, animation, render-border

I am exporting my animation as single frames (.png) I need the contents of the exported frame to only be of the animated object. I am using [Render Regions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html#render-region) in conjunction with the Crop to Render Region checkbox checked.

[image]

This works great but as my object animates it moves outside the region of my Render Region.

Is there a way to get the Render Region to follow the animation? Or is there an alternative way to only render a particular area of your scene and keep it in sync with your object's movement during animation?

Here is an example of my current output where my cube leaves the Render Region:

[image]

I would like to see the cube in each frame exported.

Comment: Should work as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45837/31447

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have the render region track an object by default, however, I did make an add-on for this exact purpose: 'Animated Render Border',
available on the Blender Market [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/animated-render-border).

[image]
*(Gif is from 2.79, but the add-on works with 2.8+.)*

The add-on can track an object by looking at the object's bounding box, or more precisely, using its vertices (if it is a mesh, curve, armature (uses bones) or lattice). It can track collections of objects and it also has a mode to allow a more manual fine tuning ('Keyframe' mode).

Comment: Thanks for posting this @ray-mairlot

Comment: If you feel this has solved your question feel free to accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Move your camera. (ctrl+ alt+ 0) / select your camera
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html
If you need your camera to follow your animation , either parent the camera (ctrl+p) to the cube or put a track-to constraint on it.
If you need a secondary camera, add a camera and then ctrl + 0 that camera for this animation close up.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add an empty and camera in location (0,0,0)
   [image]
2. Parent the camera with empty. Set the camera angle to be (0,90,0)
3. Make the empty to Track to the object you want to focus on.[image: Choose the track to object]
4. Animate your object as you wish.[image]