# Rendering large image sizes in Eevee (Over 64k pixels)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am working on creating a wrap for several walls spanning 25 to 60 feet long. People are going to be looking at these fairly close so I don’t want to go below 200 dpi for my final print quality. That being said a 60 foot wall at 200 dpi would be over 100k pixels wide and from what I understand Blender has a 64k pixel maximum render size. I am also concerned I will run out of memory even in Eevee. Is there a way I can tell Blender to render this out in chunks but from a single camera so I can preserve the perspective? Any advise on this would be most helpful. Thank you!

[image: Forest Scene Wall Wrap]

Comment: You could try using the render borders to split up your render into multiple parts. Theres a few addons that let you do this with greater precision, I'm not sure if they work in the later version though. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly
https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder/releases
https://developer.blender.org/T47267

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image isn't very big in y, there is an easy solution:
Divide the x resultion by however many chunks you want. Then select the camera and adjust the shift in x:
[image]
Keyframe it to scan the entire image and render the animation.
e.g. if you're using 50% resolution set the shift to 0.5, keyframe and then -0.5. The maximum shift is 2 wich means you can split the image into 8 chunks (I think?) max.