# Adjusting Render Region boundary

Tags: rendering, camera

It seems that at times I'm able to see editable boundaries of the render region to make a small adjust to min/max X/Y and see corner grabs to adjust an X-Y boundary.   At other times I cannot get these and have to redraw the Render Region.   How do I get these adjusts to appear/disappear?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Possible to set render border exactly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the adjustable boundaries, you need to make your camera active.
Simply click on it in the *Outliner*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want the render_border operator.
First switch into camera-mode with <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, then you can either access this operator by the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (setting a render border) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (resetting the render border to the whole frame), or by opening the search bar and typing *Render Region* into it.

Comment: please use <kbd> to mark keyboard shortcuts and not mathjax

Comment: is noted, will do from now on. Thanks for correcting all my posts :)

Comment: My question was how to get the border grabs to adjust the size, not how to specify it in the first place.  Thanks for your time, however.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212963/111042 answers my question!