# Can I save a render region?

Tags: rendering

I'd like to be able to define a *Render Region* and recall it, if possible. Is there a way to do this? As it is now, a drawn *Render Region* is only temporary, and only one can be drawn at a time.

You can see the drawn render region below, and as I work on the project, I render the animated faders again and again. I'd love it if I could get the render region consistent from time to time instead of having to redraw it.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). As an alternative - You could duplicate your camera, lower the sensor size and use lens Shift to move the view.

Comment: Nice idea, but I wanted to preserve the dimensions of the render as it is, so I'm not sure if this would work the way I need it to. If I do what you're suggesting, I'd have to diddle with the output dimensions.

Comment: related or dupe: [Possible to set render border exactly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44504/possible-to-set-render-border-exactly)

Comment: I've seen this post, and while it's somewhat helpful, it's not quite what I'm looking for. I suppose what I'm looking for isn't possible, but the idea is to be able to save a render border as an object that can be named and recalled as necessary.

I've got a bunch of animated objects in my project I need to export separately. I would like to assign render regions to each of the exported elements, so I end up with consistent output through my many revisions.

As it is, the render border is something that's drawn and deleted - it's just such a temporary entity!

Comment: Hello again :). One another solution comes to mind - you could create your own render border using a plane with a "window" cutout and a holdout shader. The plane will render as a transparent area - which takes no time to render with adaptive sampling on.

Comment: That's a great idea, too! Will try it out!

Comment: That is definitely the best solution so far - works perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script like this:

```
import bpy

max_saves = 4  # if you have that many saved regions, trying to create a new one will throw an error
               # remove old saves to create a new one

save_name = "restore_render_regions_{}.py"

out = "import bpy\n\n"

for name, scene in bpy.data.scenes.items():
    out += f"scene = bpy.data.scenes.get('{name}')\n" \
    f"if scene:\n" \
    f"    scene.render.border_min_x = {scene.render.border_min_x}\n" \
    f"    scene.render.border_max_x = {scene.render.border_max_x}\n" \
    f"    scene.render.border_min_y = {scene.render.border_min_y}\n" \
    f"    scene.render.border_max_y = {scene.render.border_max_y}\n" \
    f"# --\n\n"
    
for i in range(max_saves):
    filename = save_name.format(i)
    if filename not in bpy.data.texts:
        break
else:
    raise MemoryError("Number of saved render region states exceeded the limit - increase the limit or " \
        "remove old saves")
        
file = bpy.data.texts.new(filename)
file.write(out)
```

Running it will create another script named `restore_render_regions_{0}.py` with saved region coordinates, so you can run the automatically generated script to restore the coordinates at any time (the *Texts* are saved with the file).

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use in menu bar *View > Viewport Render Image*.