# Error "Reported texture size limit is lower than output size" How I can render large res images in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine, error

I'm trying to render a large resolution image for a wall graphic using Eevee but I get the following error message - 'Reported texture size limit is lower than output size'
My res is 23780x7913. The client likes the look of the Eevee render so would like to avoid using cycles if possible.

Comment: Hello :). There are some resolution limits for Eevee. You might need to split the render into parts and then combine. Related: [Possible to set render border exactly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44504/78972)

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try. Thanks.