# is there a way to know how many pixels are selected when cropping to render region?

Tags: measurement, dimensions

is there a way to know how many pixels are selected when cropping to render region? is there an add-on which shows how much of the area is selected. When I try to select an area to make a perfect square, its never correct.

In my first screenshot, I have made a document size 1000 x 1000 pixels.
The when I select crop to render region, the selection is an estimated guess, doing it by eye, rather than measurements.

The reason I need this method is, because sometimes I have objects in my scene which need to be rendered/exported individually from the rest of the objects in the background. So I when I render and export, and it's 205 x 209px, I then import my PNG file, and crop it in Photoshop to make it 200 x 200px.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not built-in, but as an add-on: https://github.com/p2or/blender-renderborder, also see: [Possible to set render border exactly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45837)

Comment: life savour, thanks so much!